# Is there a way to transform a full path name to just a class name for labels in a bar chart

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana

I am using ElasticSearch and Grafana to create a aggregated logging solution. The exceptions are being pushed to ElasticSearch no problem. But the library that I am using pushes the full name, for example System.Net.Socket.SocketException. These make for extremely large labels that run into each other. Is there a way to use a transform to change the label to just the class name, i.e. SocketException?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "rename by regex" transform to rename a field. I have used several to strip out the unwanted text in some fields. For example, on one dashboard I have this field name where all I want to extract "instance01":

```
servername_SQLStatistics_mssql$instance01\sql_compilations/sec
```

So my first rename by regex matches ".*mssql$" and replaces with nothing. This strips out anything up to the start of "instance01".

Then I do a second rename by regex that matches "\sql_comp.*" and replaces with nothing.